# XML Serializer - advanced features of a serializer (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This is my current code:

```
List<Tile> listTiles = new List<Tile>();

for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
{
    //Load each tile into the list
    listTiles.Add(mapbox.RenderedMap.Tiles[i, j]);
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(listTiles.GetType(), new  XmlRootAttribute("Map"));
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"savedmap.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, listTiles);
```

What it basically does is it loads every current tile onto a list, which is then serialized in the format:

```
<Map>
    <Tile>TileData</Tile>
</Map>
```

With Map being the root node.

My question is: How can I make it so instead of what I have now, I have the following?

```
<GameSave>
    <Map>
        <Tile>TileData</Tile>
    </Map>
    <Options>
    </Options>
</GameSave>
```

So basically, add a root node and put my Map node into it (which contains the Tile nodes), alongside an options node. Would I have to change the way im doing it and not use a list since, the list only contains tiles?

Comment: I'm unlear why you are concerned about that. Logically, you would try it in your code, and then ask a question here if it doesn't work.

Comment: I have very little XML experience, I'm an unclear of what to do, or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapping object with appropriate XML attributes for the serializer to understand your desired format. The following shows how that might look:

```
public class Tile
{
    public string TileData { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("GameSave")]
public class GameSave
{
    [XmlArray("Map")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Tile")]
    public List<Tile> Tiles { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Options")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Option")]
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Then, after generating your GameSave object, you will see the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GameSave xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Map>
    <Tile>
      <TileData>Test</TileData>
    </Tile>
  </Map>
  <Options>
    <Option>
      <Key>Option</Key>
      <Value>Value</Value>
    </Option>
  </Options>
</GameSave>
```

Comment: Just want to let you know that I tried it and it worked, thank you very much!(would upvote but I can't yet)